# Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when deleting record

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am following this tutorial to learn add, clear and delete records from Excel using VBA Button.

My add and delete buttons are not working properly. I don't know where it is wrong. I copied the exact code from [add/clear link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bALyD-jalwA) and [delete link](https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/delete-data-from-excel-worksheet-database-via-user-form/)

So this is my code below for add:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long, count As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow = lastrow + 1
Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1
count = 0
For i = 12 To lastrow
If TextBox1 = Cells(i, 1) Then
count = count + 1
End If

If count > 1 Then
Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 2) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 3) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 4) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 5) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 6) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 7) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 8) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 9) = ""
Cells(lastrow, 10) = ""
MsgBox ("Duplicate entry ! Name already exists!")
End If

If count = 1 Then
Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Value
Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox3.Text
Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox4.Text
Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox5.Text
Cells(lastrow, 6) = TextBox6.Text
Cells(lastrow, 7) = TextBox7.Text
Cells(lastrow, 8) = TextBox8.Text
Cells(lastrow, 9) = TextBox8.Text
Cells(lastrow, 10) = TextBox10.Text
End If
Next
End Sub
```

The above one is working fine. But it is not showing the warning message duplicate record. Even if i repeat the same records, it shows no warning. My row starts from 12.

2) Delete button is throwing error 
Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”

This is the code for delete button

```
Dim currentrow As Long


Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()

answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Record?")
If answer = vbYes Then
Cells(currentrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

currentrow = 12
TextBox1 = Cells(currentrow, 1)
TextBox2 = Cells(currentrow, 2)
TextBox3 = Cells(currentrow, 3)
TextBox4 = Cells(currentrow, 4)
TextBox5 = Cells(currentrow, 5)
TextBox6 = Cells(currentrow, 6)
TextBox7 = Cells(currentrow, 7)
TextBox8 = Cells(currentrow, 8)
TextBox9 = Cells(currentrow, 9)
TextBox10 = Cells(currentrow, 10)

End Sub
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: But i gave currentrow = 12 in Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize() and also declared outside  as  Dim currentrow As Long

Comment: You don't specify a sheet in Add which might be the problem. In the Delete you have naughtily added a 1 here `UserForm1_Initialize`. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than all other things you’ve already been told by other answerers, you are extending “For i = 12 To lastrow ... Next” loop to encompass the whole “cmdAdd()” code, while you are to close it right after your first “End If”

Then, wait adding the new record once you know there are no duplicates

Furthermore you can use Controls() property of userform object to return wanted textbox and thus alliwing you to use a loop to write or read all textboxes

Finally, use WorksheetFunction.CountIf() and avoid a loop

```
Dim currentrow As Long

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim lastrow As Long, count As Long, j As Long

    With Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(12, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1)), Me.TextBox1.Value)
        If count > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Duplicate entry ! Name already exists!")
        Else
            For j = 1 To 10
                .Cells(lastrow + 1, j) = Me.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
            Next
        End If
   End With
End Sub


Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete the record in row " & currentow & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Record?") = vbYes Then
        Sheet1.Cells(currentrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long

    currentrow = 12
    With Me
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Sheet1.Cells(currentrow, i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

As a side note, your cmdDelete() is always deleting record at row 12 unless you have some code to update “currentrow”

Comment: Hi as you said the delete is always deleting at row 12. I want delete a record by a field id . for example, i have a column with ID values. if i have to delete an ID with 1045, or other ID's.. how do i do that?

Comment: And cmdAdd() is not working. It says compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. The error is coming from this line count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells(12, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1), Me.TextBox1.Value)

Comment: Edited to correct the countif first argument. If my answer solved your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. But cmdAdd() is still not working. When i run, it shows the current 12th record in the form and when i edit and add, it shows run time error and couldn't fine specified object. The above is not actually adding any record. It is just finding record from 12th row

Comment: This line   .Cells(lastrow + 1, j) = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value  //i can;t able to add anything.

Comment: Thank you so much.. it works good. But I am unable to add more than 2 records. Any idea why?

Comment: no. now I tested it and is adding all the records I need, provided they have not duplicated id

Comment: Can we go to chat? I will share you my snapshot? I don't know why it is not adding more than 2 records

Comment: post a new question with the code and all the relevant snapshots

Answer (score 1):

A useful thing to know with VBA is that you can set a breakpoint by clicking in the left-hand margin of the coding zone. After you "Run" the code, the program stops at the breakpoint. Then you can press f8 to step through line by line, mouse-over variables to see their values, and use the Immediate window to test things out.

What is wrong with the Add Record?  VBA comparisons, like `TextBox1 = Cells(i, 1)`,  are case sensitive, so try putting:

```
Option Compare Text
```

at the top of your module.

To figure out why the cmdDelete is not working, put a breakpoint in where it says `Cells(currentrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete`.  When the code stops, move the mouse over currentrow and check its value.  If it really is 12, your code should work...  If it isn't, you need to figure out where in the module the value of `currentrow` is set.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the msgbox out the for loop and assign a value to currentrow.

```
 Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
 Dim lastrow As Long, count As Long

 lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 lastrow = lastrow + 1
 Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1
 count = 0
 For i = 12 To lastrow
 If TextBox1 = Cells(i, 1) Then
 count = count + 1
 End If

 If count > 1 Then
 Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 2) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 3) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 4) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 5) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 6) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 7) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 8) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 9) = ""
 Cells(lastrow, 10) = ""
 'MsgBox ("Duplicate entry ! Name already exists!")
 End If

 If count = 1 Then
 Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Value
 Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox3.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox4.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox5.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 6) = TextBox6.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 7) = TextBox7.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 8) = TextBox8.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 9) = TextBox8.Text
 Cells(lastrow, 10) = TextBox10.Text
 End If
 Next

 if Cells(lastrow, 1) = "" then
 MsgBox ("Duplicate entry ! Name already exists!")
 end if

 End Sub

 Dim currentrow As Long


 Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
 currentrow = 12
 answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Record?")
 If answer = vbYes Then
 Cells(currentrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
 End Sub


 Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

 currentrow = 12
 TextBox1 = Cells(currentrow, 1)
 TextBox2 = Cells(currentrow, 2)
 TextBox3 = Cells(currentrow, 3)
 TextBox4 = Cells(currentrow, 4)
 TextBox5 = Cells(currentrow, 5)
 TextBox6 = Cells(currentrow, 6)
 TextBox7 = Cells(currentrow, 7)
 TextBox8 = Cells(currentrow, 8)
 TextBox9 = Cells(currentrow, 9)
 TextBox10 = Cells(currentrow, 10)

 End Sub
```